# Core Data: How do I store a CGImageRef or custom data types?

Tags: iphone, core-data, types

my iPhone application should store some data persistantly by using Core Data functionality.

Here is a code snippet:

```
NSManagedObject *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"anEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

// ...
CGContextRef context;
// ...
[entity setContext:context];
NSError *error;
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
// ...
```

My data model defines *context*'s type as "transformable". Is this right?
At build time I get the following warning:

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'setContext:' from incompatible pointer type

How can you store a CGContextRef or in general a custom data type with Core Data? Does this require the implementation of a Encoder/Decoder?

Thank you,
Norbert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to serialize the image to an NSData (or CFData) instance first. Look at CGImageDestinationCreateWithData to do this.

Comment: There are also the convenience methods of `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and UIImagePNGRepresentation` that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598600/why-is-my-transformable-core-data-attribute-not-using-my-custom-nsvaluetransforme/1601546#1601546), I provide code for an NSValueTransformer that lets you save UIImages into a transformable attribute in Core Data.  You could do something similar for the drawn image in your context.  If you need to preserve the vector elements, you could draw to a PDF context and save the data for that representation.