# What is the difference between transformable and binary data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I recently start working on core data, please can any one tell me whats the difference between transformable and binary data. I need to store myClassObject in core data. I have created the attribute and defined its type as binary data, but at the time of storing I am getting error.

Comment: What error do you get? What type of data are you going to store within that attribute? (I mean the business view of the data, not the formal data type).

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014498/what-can-i-do-with-an-transformable-attribute-type-in-core-data-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With a binary attribute, you read and write instances of `NSData` directly.

With a transformable attribute, you read and write instances of any class that can be converted to and from `NSData`. The actual data storage is the same as with a binary attribute, but Core Data uses an `NSValueTransformer` to convert to/from `NSData` when necessary.

For example, say your managed object has an image attribute where it would be convenient to read and write `UIImage` directly. Except, `UIImage` can't be saved in Core Data. But `UIImage` can be converted to and from `NSData`. So, if you used a transformable attribute you could read and write `UIImage` while still keeping `NSData` in the data store.

Comment: Tom, Would the transformable data retain the same NSData behavior regarding external storage? (even though, the allow external storage is not explicitly in the UI, or would blobs start appearing on the Core Data Store)?   The documentation does not precisely state that the transformable attribute will be saved to an external record or the rules that will be applied. Can you share your experience?

Comment: Exactly I have the same question. There is no such option in Transformable  attribute type to be stored in "External Storage". Is this by default turned on or what?