# Core Data not automatically calling value transformer when getting / setting attribute directly in code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsvaluetransformer

If I understand correctly, the idea behind Core Data transformable attributes is:

1. implement an `NSValueTransformer` subclass with returns `[NSData
   class]` in `+transformedValueClass` along with its implementation
   for transformation
2. register the transformer in `+load` or `+initialize`
3. set an entity's attribute as transformable
4. set a name for your transformer (the name you used to register it)
   in the xcode model editor for the attribute.

At this point, I'd expect that accessing or setting the attribute in a managedObject of the appropriate entity type would trigger the value transformer. However, I'm testing this in an app that uses `AFIncrementalStore` and I get the following behavior:

- A - registering the transformer in `+load` or `+initialize` doesn't
  seem necessary; Core Data finds it anyway (though read ahead).
- B - fetch requests via `AFIncrementalStore` do trigger the
  transformer. For example, I get JSON back from a fetch request and
  when mapping the response dictionary to the managedObject, the
  transformer is triggered and coverts the appropriate dictionary key
  to `NSData` in the object.
- C - HOWEVER, if I try to set or get the attribute via code, the
  transformer is not called. That is doing something like
  `myManagedObject.myAttribute = @"hello"` does not trigger the
  conversion from `NSString` to `NSData` and neither does `NSString
  *myString = myManagedObject.myAttribute` trigger the conversion from `NSData` to `NSString`.

So what am I missing? I thought the idea was that CoreData would automatically call the transformer. Am I wrong?

According to this question: [Why is my transformable Core Data attribute not using my custom NSValueTransformer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598600/why-is-my-transformable-core-data-attribute-not-using-my-custom-nsvaluetransform)
 this seems to be a bug in the Apple frameworks. But what throws me off is that via AFIncrementalStore the value transformer does get called. Maybe the key is that by setting just an attribute via code I am not really triggering AFIncrementalStore and so the change is merely in-memory ?

Comment: I don't know anything about AFIncrementalStore, but I would assume that the inverse transformer is called when you *save* the context, not when you set an attribute. Did you check that?

Comment: you are right. that's exactly what's happening. Though the Apple docs seem to imply the transformer should also be triggered by manual (aka, via accessors in code) access to the object's attribute. Anyway, if you re-state your comment as an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(From the comment above:)* The inverse transformer is called when you *save* the context,
not when you set an attribute.