# Setters, Getters and Exposing real core data types, how do I do that?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I have a core data entity that has a structure like this:

```
number (integer 16),
reference (binary)
image (binary)
```

I have created a class for that entity.

The header of that class has these declarations for the entity property.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * reference;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * image;
```

but in fact, these 3 properties are

```
number = NSInteger
reference = NSArray
image = UIImage
```

because I cannot store arrays and images on core data directly, I have to convert it to NSData to save but I don't care for the property being declared as NSData, because the conversion to and from NSData is something internal to the entity and should not be exposed to code outside the class.

I want these header properties to be declared like

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * reference;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage * image;
```

and I want to, for example, when I assign an array to `reference` that is converted to NSData internally.

I know I have to create setters and getters to do that but my problem is that the entity is already using these names. Obviously I can rename all core data entities to have a prefix like xnumber, xreference, ximage, etc., so I will have no collisions between the names/types I want to expose and those I want to hide internally.

Is there any other alternative to that? My fear is ending with a sea of references that are similarly.

Comment: did you thought about using transformable type - NSValueTransformer ? , like they do here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598600/why-is-my-transformable-core-data-attribute-not-using-my-custom-nsvaluetransforme/1601546#1601546

Comment: I never used that but as far as I know, if I declare the values as transformable they will be exposed like id and my problem persists, right?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your description whether this would work, but maybe your core data entity should have a to-many relationship to a  separate reference entity rather than trying to store an array. Also, if you use a transformable type for your entity, you can change the type in your managed object subclass from id to the type you want it transformed to. You don't even need a custom value transformer if the object conforms to NSCoding -- the system is smart enough to know it has to convert it to an NSData object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did in your application is probably most common fail using core data. By no means you should be encouraged to use the core data classes directly as you did, do always use subclassing, categories or (best of all) use wrappers.

Since in most cases when you edit an entity in your model you wish to delete the auto generated file(s) and create new ones those files should be unmodified. This is the main reason I discourage you to use any quick fixes such as modifying the names in your model and then creating the custom setters.

Why I suggest the wrappers most is because you can build your own interface with it. You can create exactly as many methods, accessories as you need on it, you can use data protection such as having read-only parameters... So when you modify the data model there should be no difference in the application at all, when you will possibly add some extra tables for some optimisations or some internal functionality you will have no issues hiding those accessories. Other then that having an extra layer will make it very easy for you to create some caching, easy debugging since you can put a breakpoint or log to more or less any and every accessory, you can internally maintain multithreading operations...

I can understand at this point migrating your code to some other system might take a bit long but that is something *you* should consider. If the application is anything but almost done I suggest you **do** migrate it: If you create a wrapper with same properties as are already used in the application it is possible to simply change the class names where it was already used, this shouldn't take too long. If you choose to continue working as it is you will most likely encounter some much harder issues and if nothing else remember this when you will start a new application.

**Edit: Wrapper explanation and example**

By wrapper I mean a class instance that holds another instance and builds an interface around it. Let me show you a nice example first:

**Interface:**

```
@interface EntityWrapper : NSObject
@property NSInteger number;
@property UIImage *image;
+ (NSArray *)fetchAll;
+ (void)invalidateCache;
@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
@class EntityName;

static NSArray *__entityCache = nil;

@interface EntityWrapper() {
    EntityName *_boundEntity;
}
@end

@implementation EntityWrapper
- (instancetype)initWithEntity:(EntityName *)entity {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        _boundEntity = entity;
    }
    return self;
}
+ (NSArray *)fetchAll {
    if(__entityCache == nil) {
        NSMutableArray *toReturn = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSArray *entityArray = nil; //fetch from data base
        for(EntityName *entity in entityArray)
            [toReturn addObject:[[EntityWrapper alloc] initWithEntity:entity]];

        __entityCache = [toReturn copy];
    }
    return __entityCache;
}
+ (void)invalidateCache {
    __entityCache = nil;
}

- (void)setNumber:(NSInteger)number {
    _boundEntity.number = @(number);
}
- (NSInteger)number {
    return [_boundEntity.number integerValue];
}
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    _boundEntity.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
}
- (UIImage *)image {
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:_boundEntity.image];
}
@end
```

As you can see here I am building an interface around the entity using custom setters and getters. I even create a method to fetch all objects from the data base, next step might be to fetch them with some predicate or in this case rather some custom options. I also added a most simple cache just to see the concept.

The `number` is now a `NSInteger` instead of a `NSNumber` which can be quite a convenience but be careful doing this as you might need to know if `number` is `nil`. For this case you could also create another property such as `BOOL numberIsSet`.

Pretty much the same goes for the image. You need no transformers at all, just a getter and a setter (which is pretty much the same with transformers but this approach is much more dynamic).

So creating the wrapper kind of gives you the ultimate power. The idea is to create as small interface as possible and as simple as possible. That means there are just as many methods in the header file as needed, rest is hidden. The logic behind these methods can be extremely complicated but will still be maintainable since it is a closed system (does not depend on nothing but the entity), to give you an example:

**Interface:**

```
@property (readonly) NSDecimalNumber *heavyValue;
```

**Implementation:**

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)heavyValue {
    NSDecimalNumber *valueA = _boundEntity.valueA;
    NSDecimalNumber *valueB = _boundEntity.valueB;
    NSDecimalNumber *valueC = _boundEntity.valueC;

    return [[valueA decimalNumberByAdding:valueB] decimalNumberByDividingBy:valueC];
}
```

Now this is quite a standard procedure and will work great but this method can be quite heavy on the CPU. If this method is called a lot you might get to a point where you want to optimise by storing the result into the entity itself. So all you do is add another value into the model `heavyValue` and the code:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)heavyValue {
    NSDecimalNumber *toReturn = _boundEntity.heavyValue;
    if(toReturn == nil) {
        NSDecimalNumber *valueA = _boundEntity.valueA;
        NSDecimalNumber *valueB = _boundEntity.valueB;
        NSDecimalNumber *valueC = _boundEntity.valueC;

        toReturn = [[valueA decimalNumberByAdding:valueB] decimalNumberByDividingBy:valueC];
        _boundEntity.heavyValue = toReturn;
    }
    return toReturn;
}

- (void)setValueA:(NSDecimalNumber *)valueA {
    _boundEntity.valueA = valueA;
    _boundEntity.heavyValue = nil; //this invalidates the value
}
```

So that is quite an extreme change in logic behind a simple getter but the rest of your code is unharmed, it still all works as it should.

Comment: yes, I agree to that. Can you give an example with code on how can I build that wrapper? By wrapper do you mean NSValueTransformer? Please show some code. Thanks

Comment: I edited, added an example and explanation. I hope it helps you.